# Spring Data Jpa equality of two column

Tags: spring-data

I want to learn if we could write a query that has a condition like

**`List<Entity> findbyField1EqualsField2();`**

This method should not take any parameter . It should **fetch** entities which has a `field1 equals field2`. It is just a simple sql :
**`select * from entity where field1=field2.`**

But I could not find any solution yet. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Create an operation with a query as next:

```
@Query("select t from entity t where t.field1 like t.field2")
List<T> findByField1LikeFie‌ld2();
```

I don't think `findByField1LikeFie‌​ld2()`works.... you would need to do it passing a param `findByField1Like(St‌​ring param)` and for this maybe you would need to load the entity before to get the value of `field2`.